# xpages getDocument().getUniversalID()

Tags: xpages

I just want to test something about getting the UniversalID:

I create a computed field:

```
 <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3"
    value="#{javascript:Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID()}">
</xp:text>
```

When I compose the doc. content which is on a Xpage, the computed field is already having some UNID and it is changing if I hit refresh. In lotus notes programming, the UNID could be get only if the current document was saved, having the default value `@Text(@DocumentUniqueId)`.

Should I save first the Cdoc datasource to get the correct UNID? I know I'm missing something.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refresh your page in browser then actually a new document gets created. That's why you get a different UNID.

From your previous questions I know that you define your Cdoc as a data source with

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument
        var="Cdoc"
        formName="fmPersContact">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

and that means that this Cdoc is created every time you open this XPage.

Update:

In addition, you get also a different UNID every time your field gets calculated on server  when you do a *partial refresh* and document is *not saved* yet.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So, in xpages development isn't necessary to save a datasource ( as was in lotus notes : a form ) to get its UNID ?

Comment: No, it is not necessary. You get the UNID for a new created and not yet saved document in LotusScript too. Only for getting the Noteid you need to save document before.

Comment: I noticed that this UNID changes also when I just use some getComponent('MyHeadacheDialog').show() ... why ?

Comment: Probably because it causes a full update. Not the .show() though but the button which includes that code.

Comment: I did tried the partial parameter from the refreshMode property for the button but still my computed field  value ( the UNID ) described in my question is changing when I hit the button.

Comment: Just tested it: you have to Cdoc.save() before you use UNID (e.g. in your dialog). Otherwise Cdoc gets a different UNID every time you return to server and ask for getUniversalID() as long as it is not saved.

Comment: I use the action=NewDocument. The computed field value is already with the UNID. In my button: 1. Save the Cdoc. and 2. show the dialog. My UNID from the doc. content is changing before the dialog is showed.

Comment: Yes, I know. Don't use UNID *before* you called save(). In your case: don't show UNID in computed field. Use `Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID()` only *after* calling `Cdoc.save()`.

Comment: I tried this: if (Cdoc.isNewNote()) {  Cdoc.save(); }
Cdoc.setValue("computedField3",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
getComponent('exampleDialog').show() but my computed field value is still blank... arghhh. Also, I should cover the case when already saved documents are reopened and the button is clicked.

Comment: Also I tried in the PostSaveDocument of the Cdoc event: Cdoc.setValue("computedField3",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID()); but still the UNID isn't displayed...

Comment: Didn't you want to show Pdoc in your dialog? Shouldn't you set Pdoc.setValue... than?

Comment: I want to show it firstly in my Cdoc content, and then pass-it into my dialog with custom properties, using Cdoc.computedFiel3 to my field from the dialog/Pdoc.

Comment: Is computedFiel3 included in your partial refresh?

Comment: <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField3"> // this is my eventhandler from my button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55979/discussion-between-knut-herrmann-and-mfg-flay).